# Dual boot Ubuntu/Windows, single boot manager

Tags: grub2

Good day, is it possible to have both OSes using single boot manager?
I guess grub is not able to boot directly into Windows and vice versa. Maybe is there a 3rd party boot manager being able to directly boot to any OS?

Answer (score 2):

To boot into your choice of two or more OSs requires a boot menu. GRUB boot menu is an excellent choice for this if you have dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu, because GRUB (GRand Unified Bootloader) is the default bootloader in Ubuntu. Grub is compatible with GUI bootloader customization and repair tools such as Grub Customizer and Boot-Repair.

Grub can also be configured to boot directly into your choice of OS without requiring user intervention, however with this configuration it still requires user intervention to boot into the other OS.

#### Additional information:

When Ubuntu is installed in a computer that has Windows installed already (dual boot) the installation process configures grub to show you a menu where you can choose Ubuntu or Windows.

If you don't choose (the wait time is configurable) it will boot Ubuntu by default. You can configure grub to boot Windows if you don't choose. Or you can configure grub to boot the OS that was booted last. This setting works best for Windows updates and upgrades that take a long time and requires multiple reboots.

Comment: @user68186 I like that comment the way it is verbatim. Please edit my answer and add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.